# PHP To Redirect To Unique URL After Form Submit

Tags: php, forms, redirect

I've looked for this answer high and low. Maybe you can help. I've written this PHP code below which writes form field data to a random unique HTM file. Great. But I want the user to be redirected to the newly created file after the script is processed.

Here is the error I get:

"Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by"

SOLVED: See new code below please. Note Javascript in case of a browser issue.

```
 <?php


  if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {

  $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";

  $id = base_convert(microtime(false), 10, 36);

  $newurl = "https://www.wefindlenders.com/temps/$id.htm";

  $ret = file_put_contents("temps/$id.htm", $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

  if($ret === false) {
    die('There was an error writing this file');
   }
   else {

  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='{$newurl}';     </script>";
  echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=' . $newurl . '">';

 }
  }
 else {
 die('no post data to process');
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Thanks - yep - I've read all that, but all my tries fail (miserably ;-))

Comment: What tries? How could it fail with that function? Include those to your question.

Comment: Use ´header("Location:".$id.".htm");´ before ANY other output, e.g. instead of the echo

Comment: I've added the header line (thanks Reeno) but no joy. Thanks to all for their comments.

Comment: you may need to use the full address...including http://, etc

Comment: Thanks all for comments. SOLVED: whitespace before "<?php" at top of file!